# String class based on graphemes?

Tags: string, unicode, character-encoding

I'm wondering why we don't have some string classes that represent a string of Unicode grapheme clusters instead of code points or characters.  It seems to me that in most applications it would be easier for programmers to access components of a grapheme when necessary than to have to organize them from code points, which appears necessary even if only to avoid casually breaking a string in "mid-grapheme" (at least in theory).  Internally a string class might use a variable length encoding such as UTF-8, UTF-16, or in this context even UTF-32 is variable length; or implement subclasses for all of them (and optionally configure the choice at run-time so that different languages could use their optimal encodings).  But if programmers could "see" grapheme units when inspecting a string, wouldn't string handling code in general be closer to achieving correctness, and without much extra complexity?

References:
[Characters and Combining Marks](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html#7)
[Unicode implementer's guide part 4: grapheme breaking](http://useless-factor.blogspot.com/2007/08/unicode-implementers-guide-part-4.html)
[UnicodeString Class Reference](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classUnicodeString.html)
[Enumerating a string by grapheme instead of character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056866/enumerating-a-string-by-grapheme-instead-of-character)
[Strings and character encoding in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950588/strings-and-character-encoding-in-c)

Comment: Because you haven't written it?

Comment: I wonder if this is the kind of question that would be better placed on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @John, nassar: I think John's suggestion is a good one for this question

Comment: Yes, that sounds fine.  But I think there must be a good reason if everyone is still using code points--I'm wondering what the reason is.  This is a follow on from an earlier question, trying to find a good rule of thumb for doing string handling correctly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because grapheme breaks are not the only measure of correctness. And, there are different user perceived characters depending on the language/script being used. If you are concerned about normalization mode you will also want to see [Normalizer::concatenate](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classNormalizer.html#617ad4c0ed8b54eb609772bd31e1af6f).  So I would recommend just working in code units most of the time and calculating breaks when need be.